# Levenshtein questions

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

In the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm, what does this line do?:

```
    d[i][j] = Minimum (d[i-1][j]+1, d[i][j-1]+1, d[i-1][j-1] + cost);
```

Although it gets the minimum of all of those values, why is cost added to the end, and why do we have + 1 at the end of each array indexer (first two parameters)?

Comment: You will have to post more than that, because there is no standard pseudo-code implementation of named algorithms we're all familiar with, and Wikipedia is the closest thing.  The Wikipedia entry at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance doesn't have the "+ cost", so without knowing exactly what the implementation is we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a formula:

[image]

```
m(a,b) = if a==b then 0 else 1
```

The line with "min" is the recursive formula itself, the others are non-recursive cases to which the recursion leads.

Your line is using "caching" the results in array. Try to look at it as at:

```
 d(i, j) = Minimum (d(i-1, j)+1, d(i, j-1)+1, d(i-1, j-1) + cost);
```

`cost` is `m(a,b)`, and it's zero if `a==b` and one in the other case

Answer (score 1):

From the article:

```
                (
                  d[i-1, j] + 1,  // deletion
                  d[i, j-1] + 1,  // insertion
                  d[i-1, j-1] + 1 // substitution
                )
```

The algorithm's purpose is to find the cheapest path to convert one string (or list) to another string.  The "cost" for any given operation is considered in the line you've referenced.  In yours, "deletes" are considered to be a cost of 1, "inserts" also 1, and "substitution" at a variable cost.

Answer (score 0):

if you readed further, you'd know: *We can give different penalty costs to insertion, deletion and substitution. We can also give penalty costs that depend on which characters are inserted, deleted or substituted.*

you'd e.g. include some >0 cost value in the deletion part of the formula, if you suppose than a letter deletion makes a bigger difference than a letter replacement